# Is Locking CCriticalSection more than once in same thread good practice?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, locking, critical-section

In a MFC Application, I have 2 threads accessing my data, So I am using CCriticalSection Lock and Unlock to protect my data not to be acessed from 2 threads simultaneously.

From One of the thread I need to lock my data twice,

Thread 1,

```
  void ProcessFunction()
  {
         LockData();                  // LockData and unLockData internally uses CCriticalSection
         if( IsDataAvailable() )
         {

         }
         UnLockData();
  }
```

Already IsDataAvialable has LockData()

```
   IsDataAvailable()
   {
     LockData();
     bool bAvailable = .....;
     UnLockData();
     return bAvialble;
   }
```

Thread 2

```
     void Delete() 
     {
        LockData();

        ....
        UnLockData();
     }
```

When I tested the Second Lock from Thread 1 is not waiting for first Lock to call unlock,

But one Lock from a thread is waiting for another thread to call unlock.

I understood Lock of one thread will wait for Lock count to become 0 by another thread.  But it won't wait for the same thread to unlock if locked by same thread. This is the expected behaviour.

I want to know whether calling Lock more than once in same thread is good practice or not?

Comment: AFAIK what you described is expected behavior. The purpose of `lock count` is to allow multiple locks from the same thread.

Answer (score 4):

The term of art you may be looking for here is "recursive mutex" or "reentrant mutex."  The question is, does CCriticalSection support recursive locking (locking when already locked in the same thread)?  And from what I can tell (e.g. http://microsoft.public.vc.mfc.narkive.com/gjxzQaHf/ccriticalsection), it does.

Here's an interesting discussion about recursive mutexes, which says you should not use them: http://www.zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html

Answer (score 2):

This is called a "recursive lock".

Some people don't like them. You have written a function `IsDataAvailable()` that is sometimes called with the lock held and sometimes called when it isn't held. In this case it doesn't need to know which because it takes the lock across everything it does, but it's still somewhat dangerous to write functions like that. Code that does locking *should* know what locks are already held in order to use locks correctly. Examples include avoiding locking inversion, and to ensure that if you need to *release* a lock (for example when using condition variables) that you can do so without creating problems for your caller who thought the lock was held the whole time.

You can always satisfy the people who don't like recursive locks, by writing two versions of `IsDataAvailable()`: one to calculate the value without locking, and another one that takes the lock, calls the first, and releases the lock. Then call the "right" one in any given context.

This can end up creating quite a lot of variant functions, though. If you use recursive locks correctly there's nothing really wrong with them, so you have to judge whether the additional work will help you to always use your locks correctly.

Comment: In the case of my program given I know IsDataAvailable uses Lock and all other functions which access my data has locking. So I want to do the Lock  in ProcessFunction to make sure when processing is happening deletion should not happen. So I want to know whether locking more than once is good or not?

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian: I'm not going to just tell you what to do. People who say that something is "bad practice" without explaining the problems with it either don't know what they're talking about, or just don't think they have time to make you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using recursive locking has use cases, but this isn't one of them... So no, this is not good practice. 99% of the time thread safety should not be done *inside* an object (or conceptual object, which might be your case) so that the object can be used in different threads which are outside the object.

This is a matter of separation of concerns and the generic use of your objects. `data` may need to be used single threaded sometime, in which case you don't want locks on all these operations. Even if that isn't the case, conceptually data belongs in `data`, and if you want to safely use `data` across multiple threads you should handle that elsewhere.

Separating these concepts opens up lots of flexibility: You can use different kinds of locking, like `shared_mutex`, etc. You can use the same lock for manipulating multiple objects.

This might seem like it will dirty up your code with locking everywhere. That's somewhat true. There are patterns you can use to help... like [`monitor`](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism).